# When $M$ is a submodule of $M[t^{-1}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, power-series, laurent-series

Take $X=\mathbb{C}[[t]]$ and $M$ an $X$ module. I was reading the following statement:

> If M is flat as $X-$module then $M$ can be seen as submodule of $M[t^{-1}]$

Now, I think that I can prove it using the flatness, the idea is watching
$$ M \cong M\otimes_XX \hookrightarrow M \otimes \mathbb{C}[[t]][t^{-1}]\cong M[t^{-1}].$$

Now, I think that is always true that $M$ is an $X$-submodule of $M[t^{-1}]$. I'd appreciate any type of help

Comment: If $t$ acts nilpotently this is definitely impossible! But flat does imply torsion free, though, so in case "always" means "always when flat" that's Ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $M \to M[t^{-1}], m \mapsto \frac{m}{1},$ is injective if and only if the map $M \to M, m \mapsto tm,$ is.

Comment: Ok, so in the case of flatness my attempt of proof is right?